# XMLStarlet: Using xpath to move an element to be before another one

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Given:

```
<x>
  <a />
  <d />
  <b />
  <c />
  <e />
  <f />
</x>
```

I would like to use xmlstarlet to move `<d />` to be before `<e />`.

The closest I've got is:

```
echo .. | xml ed -m "//d" "//e"
```

Which produces:

```
<e>
  <d/>
</a>
```

This is unfortunately the example the manual gives.

```
echo .. | xml ed -m "//d" "//x"
```

Puts `<d />` at the end, which is not the right place.

I tried to get `preceding-sibling` to work (if indeed that is right approach), but while:

```
echo .. | xml sel -t -c "//e/preceding-sibling::*[1]"
```

Results in `<c />`, that query doesn't work as a move destination (it complains that move destination is not a single node), nor would it really, since best case would be it would end up inside `<c />`.

I'm not sure if `ed -m` is the wrong approach, of if there is a form of XPATH which points to a location between elements instead of an element.

**Edit:** interestingly insert works more like how I'd expect, inserting what you pass it before the element picked with xpath:

```
$ xml ed -i "//c" -t elem -n "foo" -v "bar" test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x>
  <a/>
  <d/>
  <b/>
  <foo>bar</foo>
  <c/>
  <e/>
  <f/>
</x>
```

Unfortunately the value passed (`bar` above) cannot be XML, so I could pick it out of somewhere with sel and then inject it in with this command I don't think.

Comment: This seems like it should be easy. If it is, I'm not seeing it. Are you open to using XSLT with xmlstarlet? It is easy in XSLT.

Comment: @DanielHaley that's true… I didn't consider just writing the xslt myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it should be easy using `ed`. If it is, I'm not seeing it. (I don't use xmlstarlet very often.)

You may need to use XSLT...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::d)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../d"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command Line**

```
$ xml tr test.xsl test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
  <d/>
  <e/>
  <f/>
</x>
```

Comment: FWIW I'm actually trying to replace some `sed` code for a much gnarlier problem that at its base is moving an element, because the `sed` code is so nuts I can't actually work out what it does except by running it