# What is the XML/XPath expression to use with xmlstarlet to move an element to be the first element?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Folder>
      <name>Assets and Risks</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Asset_4000</name>
        <description>Address: 2286</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Risk_2000</name>
        <description>Address: 32</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Folder>
      <name>The second folder</name>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I want to use xmlstarlet (preferably all command line rather than XSLT) to move the Placemark for Risk_2000 to be the first Placemark within the same Folder (ie. before the Placemark for Asset_4000).

I know the first part is:

```
xmlstarlet edit --move "//_:kml/_:Document/_:Folder[_:name=\"Assets and Risks\"]/_:Placemark[_:name=\"Risk_2000\"]" **But What Goes Here**
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination for `xmlstarlet edit`'s `--move` must be a single node,
so work around:

- insert temporary element at position N
- update it from source element
- delete source element
- rename temporary element

(For a non-GNU/Linux platform adjust quoting and line continuation
characters in following command.)

```shell
xmlstarlet edit -N v='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' \
    --insert '//v:Folder[v:name="Assets and Risks"]/v:Placemark[1]' \
        --type elem --name 'Placemark_TMP' --value '' \
    --update '$xstar:prev' --expr '../v:Placemark[v:name="Risk_2000"]/node()' \
    --delete '$xstar:prev/../v:Placemark[v:name="Risk_2000"]' \
    --rename '$xstar:prev' --value 'Placemark' \
  file.xml | xmlstarlet format --nsclean
```

`xmlstarlet edit` code can use the convenience `$xstar:prev` (aka
`$prev`) node to refer to the node created by the most recent
`-i / --insert`, `-a / --append`, or `-s / --subnode` option. Examples
of `$xstar:prev` are given in
[doc/xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt) and
the source code's examples/ed-backref*.

`--expr '../v:Placemark[…]/node()'` makes a deep copy of element's
child nodes but not its attributes
([background](https://web.archive.org/web/20180305021934/dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N1553.html#d2256e190)).
The element in question has no attributes, otherwise use the XPath
`--expr '../v:Placemark[…]/node() | ../v:Placemark[…]/@*'`.

The `--nsclean` step removes redundant namespace declarations.

Since `xmlstarlet` supports [exslt](/questions/tagged/exslt) there may be possibilities in the
[set:leading](http://exslt.org/set/functions/leading/index.html) or
[set:trailing](http://exslt.org/set/functions/trailing/index.html)
functions but I didn't look into it.

For a stylesheet-based approach see
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959317/xmlstarlet-using-xpath-to-move-an-element-to-be-before-another-one).

---

**UPDATE** 2021-09-29

The code above can be rewritten as follows using

- short commands and options
- the `--var <name> <xpath>` option (in
  [doc/xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
  but not in the user's guide)
- the default namespace [shortcut](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html) `_:`

and adding `| $src/@*` to include attributes:

```shell
xmlstarlet ed \
    --var dir '//_:Folder[_:name="Assets and Risks"]' \
    --var tgt '$dir/_:Placemark[1]' \
    --var src '$dir/_:Placemark[_:name="Risk_2000"]' \
    -i '$tgt' -t elem -n 'Placemark_TMP' -v '' \
    -u '$xstar:prev' -x '$src/node() | $src/@*' \
    -d '$src' \
    -r '$xstar:prev' -v 'Placemark' \
    file.xml | xmlstarlet fo -N
```

Comment: Whilst this is quite complex (due to the way xmlstarlet move works) it works exactly how I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works - but, due to the way xmlstarlet's `--move` works, instead of moving "the Placemark for Risk_2000 to be the first Placemark within the same Folder", you have to move the current first Placemark to the bottom of the first `Folder` element. You also have to declare the default namespace.

So try:

```
xml edit -N x="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"  \
--move "//x:Placemark[.//.='Asset_4000']" "//x:Folder[1]" file.xml
```

The output (given your xml above) should be your expected output.

Comment: Whilst this may work, I didn't test it as I really want to move the item to the top rather than move the current top out of the way but thanks for the tips.