# Shell script to manipulate xml file tags

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have a big xml file with many many `programme` tags in it. One example entry looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tv generator-info-name="none" generator-info-url="none">
  <programme start="20240130225000 +0000" stop="20240130234000 +0000" channel="SUPER.RTL.de">
    <title lang="de">Rizzoli &amp; Isles</title>
    <sub-title lang="de">Mord in der Kirche</sub-title>
    <desc lang="de">Bei der Taufe von Janes (Angie Harmon) Neffen jagt eine Überraschung die andere: Erst eröffnet die Kindsmutter, dass sie mit Baby, aber ohne den Vater nach Texas umsiedeln will, dann entdeckt Pathologin Maura (Sasha Alexander) eine Tote unter dem Taufbecken.</desc>
    <credits>
      <director>Norman Buckley</director>
      <actor role="Jane Rizzoli">Angie Harmon</actor>
      <actor role="Maura Isles">Sasha Alexander</actor>
      <actor role="Angela Rizzoli">Lorraine Bracco</actor>
      <actor role="Det. Barry Frost">Lee Thompson Young</actor>
      <actor role="Det. Vince Korsak">Bruce McGill</actor>
      <actor role="Frankie Rizzoli Jr.">Jordan Bridges</actor>
      <actor role="Casey Jones">Chris Vance</actor>
      <composer>James S. Levine</composer>
    </credits>
    <date>2013</date>
    <category lang="de">Krimiserie</category>
    <icon src="https://images.tvtoday.de/itv/2024-01-30/56325176ea60e556a31a3911_780.jpg" />
    <country lang="de">USA</country>
    <episode-num system="onscreen">S4 E3/16</episode-num>
    <rating system="FSK">
      <value>FSK 12</value>
    </rating>
    <star-rating system="FSK">
      <value>3/3</value>
    </star-rating>
  </programme>
  .... many more to come ...
</tv>
```

I want to manipulate it that way so I get all tags AFTER `</desc>` to be within the `<desc>` tag. So the final xml should look:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <tv generator-info-name="none" generator-info-url="none">
    <programme start="20240130225000 +0000" stop="20240130234000 +0000" channel="SUPER.RTL.de">
      <title lang="de">Rizzoli &amp; Isles</title>
      <sub-title lang="de">Mord in der Kirche</sub-title>
      <desc lang="de">Bei der Taufe von Janes (Angie Harmon) Neffen jagt eine Überraschung die andere: Erst eröffnet die Kindsmutter, dass sie mit Baby, aber ohne den Vater nach Texas umsiedeln will, dann entdeckt Pathologin Maura (Sasha Alexander) eine Tote unter dem Taufbecken.
      
      Director: Norman Buckley
      Jane Rizzoli - Angie Harmon
      Maura Isles - Sasha Alexander
      Angela Rizzoli">Lorraine Bracco
      Det. Barry Frost">Lee Thompson Young
      Det. Vince Korsak">Bruce McGill
      Frankie Rizzoli Jr. - Jordan Bridges
      Casey Jones - Chris Vance
      Composer: James S. Levine
      
      2013
      Krimiserie
      
      USA
      S4 E3/16
      FSK 12
      3/3</desc>
    </programme>
</tv>
```

In short... more or less put (the strings of) every tag after `</desc>` into the `<desc> TEXT </desc>` tag.

This should run on a very limited linux box. I have python3 available with these possible packages regarding xml:

```bash
# list xml |grep pyth
libxml2-python - 2.10.4-r0 - XML C Parser Library and Toolkit
python3-lxml - 4.9.2-r0 - Powerful and Pythonic XML processing library combining libxml2/libxslt with the ElementTree API.
python3-xml - 3.11.2-r0 - Python basic XML support
python3-xmlrpc - 3.11.2-r0 - Python XML-RPC support
```

**Update: I've searched a little and came up with my solution, see my answer below.**

Comment: What have you tried after doing some research? (like finding: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401677/how-exactly-does-xmlstarlet-move-work  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959317/xmlstarlet-using-xpath-to-move-an-element-to-be-before-another-one ? )

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched a little and came up with below python script (which uses xml.etree.ElementTree). Did re-arrange some parts and append the sub-title and the desc tag with the infos. So far it works!

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()
tree = ET.parse('epg.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Show current XML
# ET.dump(root)

cnt = 0
for x in tree.iter('programme'):

    # Director (<credits><director></diretcor>....</credits>)
    director = x.find('./credits/director')
    if director is not None:
        director_str = '\nDirector: ' + str((x.find('./credits/director').text or ''))
    else:
        director_str = ''

    # Actor(s) (<credits><director></diretcor><actor role="Movie Name">Real Name</actor><actor....>Real Name</actor>...</credits>)
    actor_str = '\n'
    for actor in x.findall('./credits/actor'):
        if 'role' in actor.attrib:
            actor_str = actor_str + '\n' + str(actor.attrib["role"]) + ' - ' + str(actor.text)
        else:
            actor_str = actor_str + '\n' + str(actor.text)
    # Composer - not needed, so left out here

    # Remove <credits> subelement(s)
    credits = x.find('credits')
    if credits is not None:
        x.remove(credits)

    # Date (<date></date>)
    date = x.find('date')
    if date is not None:
        date_str = ' ║ ' + str(date.text or '')
        # date_str = '\n' + str((x.find('date').text or ''))
        x.remove(date)
    else:
        date_str = ''

    # Category (<category></category>)
    category = x.find('category')
    if category is not None:
        category_str = ' ║ ' + str(category.text or '')
        # category_str = '\n' + str((x.find('category').text or ''))
        x.remove(category)
    else:
        category_str = ''

    # Country (<country lang="de">USA</country>)
    country = x.find('country')
    if country is not None:
        country_str = ' ║ ' + str(country.text or '')
        # country_str = '\n' + str((x.find('country').text or ''))
        x.remove(country)
    else:
        country_str = ''

    # Episode (<episode-num system="onscreen">S4 E3/16</episode-num>)
    episode = x.find('episode-num')
    if episode is not None:
        episode_str = ' ║ ' + str(episode.text or '')
        # episode_str = '\n' + str(episode.text or '')
        x.remove(episode)
    else:
        episode_str = ''

    # Rating FSK (<rating system="FSK"><value>FSK 12</value></rating>)
    rating = x.find('rating/value')
    if rating is not None:
        rating_str = ' ║ ' + str(rating.text or '')
        x.remove(x.find('rating'))
    else:
        rating_str = ''

    # Rating FSK (<rating system="FSK"><value>FSK 12</value></rating>)
    star_rating = x.find('star-rating/value')
    if star_rating is not None:
        star_rating_str = ' (' + str(star_rating.text or '') + ')'
        x.remove(x.find('star-rating'))
    else:
        star_rating_str = ''

    # Remove <icon> - not used in enigma2 epg info
    icon = x.find('icon')
    if icon is not None:
        x.remove(x.find('icon'))

    # Append <desc> - Max. char 2300
    desc = x.find('desc')
    if desc is not None:
        # new_desc = str(desc.text) + str(episode_str) + str(director_str) + str(actor_str) + str(date_str) + str(category_str) + str(country_str)
        new_desc = str(desc.text) + str(actor_str) + str(director_str)
        desc.text = str(new_desc)
    else:
        desc = ''

    # Append <sub-title> - Max. char 160
    # Emple: <sub-title lang="de">Der Horrorclown ║ Help! My House Is Haunted ║ Dokuserie ║ S4E6/15 ║ 2022 ║ GB</sub-title>
    sub_title = x.find('sub-title')
    if sub_title is not None:
        sub_title_str = str(sub_title.text or '')
        sub_title.text = str(sub_title_str) + str(category_str) + str(episode_str) + str(date_str) + str(rating_str) + str(country_str)
    else:
        # create new element <sub-title> and set text
        sub_title = ET.SubElement(x, "sub-title")
        sub_title.set('lang', 'de')
        sub_title.text = str(category_str).replace(' ║ ', '') + str(episode_str) + str(date_str) + str(rating_str) + str(star_rating_str) + str(country_str)

    cnt += 1

print('Total EPG processed: ', cnt)

# write the changed tree to a file
tree.write("epg_ripper_example_new.xml", encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)

end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use Powershell and put output into a CSV file.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$programmes = $xDoc.Descendants("programme")

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($programme in $programmes)
{
   $start = $programme.Attribute('start').Value
   $stop = $programme.Attribute('stop').Value
   $channel = $programme.Attribute('channel').Value
   $title = $programme.Element('title').Value
   $subtitle = $programme.Element('sub-title').Value
   $description = $programme.Element('desc').Value

   $credits = $programme.Element('credits')
   $director = $credits.Element('director').Value

   $date = $programme.Element('date').Value
   $category = $programme.Element('category').Value
   $icon = $programme.Element('icon').Attribute('src').Value
   $country = $programme.Element('country').Value
   $episode = $programme.Element('episode-num').Value
   $rating = $programme.Element('rating').Element('value').Value
   $star = $programme.Element('star-rating').Element('value').Value

   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
      Start = $start
      Stop = $stop
      Channel = $channel
      Title = $title
      'Sub Title' = $subtitle
      Description = $description
      Director = $director
      Date = $date
      Category = $category
      ICON = $icon
      Country = $country
      Episode = $episode
      Rating = $rating
      Star = $star
   }
   foreach($actor in $credits.Elements('actor'))
   {
       $name = 'Role ' + $actor.Attribute('role').Value
       $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $name -NotePropertyValue $actor.Value
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks - but as said this has to be done on that small linux box (no Powershell) and also the whole file structure has to be intact (xml with the given element tags). I've updated my 1st post with a python script which more or less works as it should. Don't know if this can be improved. 

```bash
Total EPG processed:  27258
Duration: 0:00:53.171503
```
At the moment it takes 53 sec. for 27k xml elements. Not too bad I think (for this low cpu box).